# Wordpress separate comment and pingback on twenty ten theme

Tags: php, wordpress

How to separate `comments` and `pingbacks` to the [**Twenty Ten theme**](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten)? (default wordpress theme)

According to the `functions.php`

```
function twentyten_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
    case '' :
?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 40 ); ?>
        <?php printf( __( '%s <span class="says">says:</span>', 'twentyten' ), sprintf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .comment-author .vcard -->
    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
        <em><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentyten' ); ?></em>
        <br />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
        <?php
            /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
            printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentyten' ), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'twentyten' ), ' ' );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .comment-meta .commentmetadata -->

    <div class="comment-body"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>

    <div class="reply">
        <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .reply -->
</div><!-- #comment-##  -->

<?php
        break;
    case 'pingback'  :
    case 'trackback' :
?>
<li class="post pingback">
    <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentyten' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __('(Edit)', 'twentyten'), ' ' ); ?></p>
<?php
        break;
endswitch;
}
 endif;
```

I was google and have tons results, but all in old version. Let me know if can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of wordpress you are using, not on the theme.
Maybe this is helpful: http://themocracy.com/2010/02/separate-pingbacks-user-comments/